# Linking Libraries that contain circular references in GCC

Tags: gcc, linker, static-libraries

I am trying to link an application with multiple static libraries in GCC.

There are two libraries that cause problems. Libsupport provides a terminal for the application. It relies on libcpu to provide a serial link, timing and syncronisation. Libcpu relies on libsupport to provide queueing for serial data and more.

If I specify libsupport first when linking libcpu cannot be linked with the queue functions. Is I specify libcpu first lib support can not link the serial link (and more) functions.

It looks like GCC parses a library only once and discard any unused objects.

Can I ask gcc to parse libraries multiple times or to include all objects?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
gcc ... -lsupport -lcpu -lsupport -lcpu
```

-> Each mention of a library will cause resolution of libraries that came before it (but not necessarily ones specified afterwards), which is why you may need to specify more "-lsupport -lcpu" in future.

Alternatively, try `--start-group -lsupport -lcpu --end-group` once.

Comment: The group specifier is interesting..  never seen it before.

Answer (score 7):

[Here](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) is detailed explanation of why either repeating libraries or using `--start/--end-group` is required in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can normally specify a library more than once to get around this kind of problem, e.g.

```
$ gcc ... -lsupport -lcpu -lsupport ...
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. Then I tried "-lsupport -lcpu -lsupport -lcpu" and it worked. Not sure what is happing but the application is linking.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `--start-group` /  `--end-group` are linker options which are unknown to the compiler, so if you use `gcc` / `g++` for linking, you should specify them as:

```
gcc ... -Wl,--start-group -lsupport -lcpu -Wl,--end-group
```

Otherwise you will get:

> gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command-line option '--start-group'

> gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command-line option '--end-group'