# How do i link sources while ignoring the linking order?

Tags: c++, linker

I tried to recreate a little test I did a few days ago, and although the code is not the same as it was back then, it works in a similar way. I know how the linker works, and that it ignores everything, that is not used at the time it starts to link a file. So I have test.cpp, test2.cpp, test.h, test2.h and main.cpp.

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

void Test(void);
void TestTestTest(void);

#endif /* TEST_H */
```

test2.h

```
#ifndef TEST2_H
#define TEST2_H

void TestTest(void);

#endif /* TEST2_H */
```

test.cpp

```
#include <test.h>
#include <test2.h>
#include <iostream>

void Test(void)
{
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
}

void TestTestTest(void)
{
    TestTest();
    std::cout << "TestTestTest" << std::endl;
}
```

test2.cpp

```
#include <test2.h>
#include <test.h>
#include <iostream>

void TestTest(void)
{
    Test();
    std::cout << "TestTest" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <test.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    TestTestTest();
    return 0;
}
```

And the linking order: main.o test.o test2.o

I know, that the source for function Test will be ignored while linking test.o, but TestTestTest will not be ignored, because there is a function call in main.cpp that uses TestTestTest. When linking test2.o TestTest will not be ignored, because it is used in function TestTestTest. But TestTest has a function call to the function Test, that has been ignored previously, so I get an error message.

Is there any way around that, so that the order does not madder, or that it takes all the functions source, and cuts out at the end, what is not needed?

I have heard of the linker option -fPIC, that is used when compiling shared libraries. But for some reason, when I compile all the sources except main.cpp and link them together in a shared library, and link that library to main.o, Windows says, that it can't run the application, although it was built without any problem. And i don't understand, why this is happening.

I used g++ for building my code.

Is it possible to build the source this way, and if it is possible, what am i doing wrong? And is there anything i have to keep in mind, when building shared libraries?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802624/linking-libraries-that-contains-circular-refrences-in-gcc

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me out. I didn't know that I can use libraries multiple times, I always thought, that there would be an error because the function then would have been defined multiple times. But apperently, that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use attribute:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```

while creating shared libraries in Windows with every function you want to use.

For example test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

void __declspec(dllexport) Test(void);
void __declspec(dllexport) TestTestTest(void);

#endif /* TEST_H */
```

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/a90k134d.aspx).